# Regex to convert directory paths in PHP

Tags: php, regex, path

Goal -
convert a path: `/aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/dddd` 
to a relative path (to the root): `../../../../`

So far I've come up with this regex: `/\/.+?\//`
but this only produces: `..bbbbb..dddd` because it is only matching every other pair of slashes, and also matching the slashes. I'm looking for something like a string split, but also replace.

All of my php code:

```
$pattern = '/\/.+?\//';
$path = '/aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/dddd';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '..', $path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_replace(':/[^/]+:', '../', $path);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\/{0,1}(\w+)\/{0,1}/', '../', $path);
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Yes. It works for me. It makes exactly the changes you want. It changes every directory to `../`. http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/55O At that link, set the replacement string to `../` and then choose `preg_replace`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I misread :-(, +1. But you could replace `{0,1}` by `?` and use another delimiter to avoid escaping.

Answer (score 0):

what about the below ?

```
$pattern = '/\//';
$path = '/aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/dddd';
preg_replace(array($pattern), array('..'), $path
```

Comment: Why are you using `arrays` in `preg_replace`? And this will replace all slashes by double dot, that's not what it is asked.

Comment: sorry missunderstood the need.